# Use android dependency from Azure DevOps public artifact

Tags: android, gradle, azure-devops

I have a public artifact on Azure DevOps where I have an Android dependency. According to DevOps it says that to add it to the project I need

1. Connect to feed

```
maven {
    url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_packaging/myartifactfeed/maven/v1'
}
```

2. Get the package

```
compile(group: 'mycompany.myproject', name: 'myartifactfeed', version: '0.1.0')
```

The problem is that when I run `gradle build` I get the following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalRelease'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find mycompany.myproject:myartifactfeed:0.1.0.
     Required by:
         project :app
```

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.3.72"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_packaging/myartifactfeed/maven/v1'
        }
    }
}
```

**app/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile(group: 'mycompany.myproject', name: 'myartifactfeed', version: '0.1.0')    
}
```

So how exactly sould I be importing my dependency from DevOps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that moving `maven.url` from `buildscript` to `allprojects` did work.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // ...
        /* maven {
            url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_packaging/myfeed/maven/v1'
        } */
    }
    // ...
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        // ...
        maven {
            url 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/mycompany/myproject/_packaging/myfeed/maven/v1'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Pablo, Clad that the the problem no longer brothers you, and thanks for sharing your  answer. Could you please mark your answer as the solution of this topic? This may be very helpful to other people who are looking for a solution for the similar problems. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make sure the specified dependency version you want to install is existing in the feed of Azure Artifacts on Azure DevOps.

Then you can reference to the following article to try installing the dependency from Azure Artifacts.

- [**Install a Maven artifact using Gradle in an Azure DevOps Services build**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/gradle/pull-package-gradle?view=azure-devops)